# Using a for loop inside brackets

Tags: javascript

It's often possible to surround code in brackets, which can be useful when creating comma expressions.

Why does the code below have syntax errors when surrounding certain code with brackets?

```js
let o = {a: 2, b: 3}

console.log('hello')    // works
(console.log('hello'))  // works

{console.log('hello')}    // works
({console.log('hello')})  // colon or comma expected

for(const k in o) console.log(k)      // works
(for(const k in o) console.log(k))    // error: newline or semicolon expected

for(const k in o) {console.log(k)}    // works
(for(const k in o) {console.log(k)})  // error: statement expected
```

Comment: Unless you're knowledgeable enough to avoid the pitfalls of ASI, use semicolons. Even if you understand ASI, it could be a good idea to use semicolons anyway.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, I read the linked question, but I'm still confused: are you saying that javascript is failing to insert semicolons? If so, how can I add semicolons to fix this? Or are you saying that javascript is automatically inserting semicolons where they shouldn't be?

Comment: You are not ending the statements where you think you are, even though they're on separate lines, because semicolons are not being automatically inserted - better not to rely on ASI to always do things as you're expecting it to, be explicit and you won't be surprised.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm having difficulty reconciling your comment with the specifics of why this won't work, even if it's the entirety of the code: `let o = {a: 2, b: 3}; (for(const k in o) console.log(k))`. Now there is only one line. I don't think you've explained exactly where the problem is...

Comment: Ah, the snippet in the question produces errors due to ASI, so I thought that's what the issue you were asking about was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` constructs are *statements*. Statements are parts of the language that *do something* - such as declare a variable, or conditionally run a block, or start a loop.

In contrast, some things are *expressions*, which evaluate to a value. Your `{a: 2, b: 3}` is an example of something that can be evaluated as an object literal, an expression. `console.log` calls (and all function calls) are also expressions; they evalute to values.

Statements can't evaluate to values because a statement *does* something on its own, and interpreting it as a value as part of something else just doesn't make sense. Putting something inside of parentheses will only be syntactically valid if that "something" is an expression; if it's a statement as well, then it can't be evaluated to a value. For similar reasons, none of the following lines are valid:

```
const val1 = (if (true) {});
const val2 = (const foo = 'foo';);
const val3 = (while(false) {});
```

Comment: Aha, yes, you nailed it, thanks